# Error 651 while connecting to PPPOE network on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, pppoe

I have recently installed Windows 8.1 on my computer and I can't get it to connect to my ISP (RDS - Romania).

My ISP uses PPPOE, so I have created a Broadband Connection with the user name and password they provided. However, every time I try to connect it fails and displays: Error 651 - The modem (or other connecting device) has reported an error.

I have already checked with my ISP and the connection works fine, they even tested it on a laptop with Windows 7.

Please note that the connection worked previously on my hardware (on Windows 7 and various Linux distros).

So, it seems the issue is Windows 8.1 specific. I have tried the following (without success):

- resetting the PC
- resetting the fiber-optic terminal in my house
- deleting and re-creating the connection
- reinstalling the network adapter from the Device Manager
- running the Windows network troubleshooter
- The solution described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2716537/en-us

Does anybody know a possible fix for this issue?

Comment: I work for an ISP here, and often when we get that error, if the user just unplugs every cable and recables the connection, the error goes away. Maybe check for a loose cable, or a damaged port?